# Google Places API: Place Details limited to 5 Reviews

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/#PlaceDetails

The "reviews" output list is apparently limited to the top 5 reviews.  This isn't mentioned at all in the documentation.  Is there way to get paginated results or more than 5?

Answer (score 7):

This is explicit stated in the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details?hl=en#Place), under the `reviews[]` field explaination:

> reviews[] a JSON array of up to five reviews.

There is currently no way to retrieve more than 5 reviews. If you think this would be a valuable feature you can submit a `Places API - Feature Request` [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request).

Comment: Ahh..  I was looking for "5" in the document.  I wish they had been more clear in writing "five (5)" for clarity.

Looks like reviews are sorted chronologically, but I can imagine that might be some other algo...

I have made a request to not just go beyond the 5, but to allow for better filtering.

http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4300

Comment: ...4 years later: your request did not much attention from Google since the time you wrote it unfortunately. Quite surprising seeing how much effort they are doing to get people to add places & relevant info (pics, reviews, & so on).

Comment: Still there is no way to get all review from google map?

Comment: If you manage the Google Business Profile for the location (i.e. you are the owner, or are shared management or oAuth access), all the Reviews data is available via GBP API.

Answer (score 2):

You can now actually get all of the reviews, all you need to do is use a Google's My Business API. Specifically the [`batchGetReviews`](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/batchGetReviews) call.

There is more work to do for you, but it meets all requirements for sorting/filtering reviews.

[Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/)

Comment: that is the correct answer in 2023