# How to get more than 5 reviews from G+ Places?

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, review

I found some threads here telling that Google API (places/+/etc.) do not allow more than 5 reviews in the response. However, it appeared most of those were as old as from 2012.

Is this still the case? Is there a difference whether I am the owner of the page/place I want to get reviews for? Most appear to operate on place ID but if I want to pull the reviews of my own business, can that be done or is it subject to the same 5 limit that appears here https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#PlaceDetailsRequests

I have been trying to find information on this for hours as it seems ... silly to think there'd be no way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google now has (although closed) API called "Google My Business" which allows fetching all reviews for a business and other location management. That solved the issue for me.

Comment: Can you please share how you did that ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a limitation of the Google Places API: Place Details, so far there is no updates regarding this issue, please see this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11624146/5995040) for further details. You can also follow this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=7630) regarding the enhancement request to get more than 5 reviews from the API. Hope this helps.