# Getting 'Most Helpful' instead of 'Latest' reviews from Google Map API

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-maps, meteor, google-maps-api-3

The Google Places API display 5 reviews from a location. 
But I noticed that these reviews are sorted by "Most Helpful" and not by "Latest".

Could there be some consideration around displaying the reviews by "Latest"?

Is there any way around to get Latest reviews from 
Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is actually being requested in Google's Issue Tracker. I encourage you to star it to be updated on the feature request.
Here's the link: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35821903

Based on the last comment there, if you are the business owner you can view the latest reviews with the [Google My Business API](https://developers.google.com/my-business/)

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have a concern that what if I am not the owner of the business?

Comment: And can have you any idea how can I get more than 5 reviews from Google, I just talked with google guy and I got the response that there is no way to get review data more than 5,  but I have also seen some of the websites that can able to somehow managed to get more than 5 reviews, can you have any idea how is it possible?

Comment: If you are not the owner of the business, then there is no way at the moment. See [another answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490835/how-to-get-more-than-5-reviews-from-g-places)

About getting more than 5 reviews, there is also a feature request on that in Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35825957)