# Get more than 5 reviews from Google API for other location

Tags: google-api, google-places-api

We are developing a web application some of our  clients have requested to have a feature to show their Google reviews on the website.

I know it's been asked before

[How to get more than 5 reviews from G+ Places?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37490835/how-to-get-more-than-5-reviews-from-g-places)

[Get more than 5 reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223719/to-get-more-than-5-reviews-from-google-places-api#:%7E:text=In%20order%20to%20have%20access,shell%20out%20a%20pretty%20penny.)

Our scenario is slightly different, we need to share our own Google API Key on all clients' websites and each client need to enter its own Google Place ID

In this case is it only us who need to have Google Business Premium Plan to get more than 5 reviews or each client is also need to go through the same plan?