# Google Place API limit to 5 reviews

Tags: google-places-api

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details?hl=en, I can only get to 5 reviews after retrieving the Place Id.

If I sign up for the Premium Data Plan for Google, can I get all the reviews even if I am NOT the business owner?

I am currently using the Go as you go plan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Places API: Place Details limited to 5 Reviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623912/google-places-api-place-details-limited-to-5-reviews)

Comment: Not really, that's from 2012, but then I read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223719/to-get-more-than-5-reviews-from-google-places-api. It says that get Premium Data Access from Google, but I can't find any other reference that supports it

Comment: It's from 2012, but the [linked documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/details?hl=en#Place) still says that `reviews[]` is "A JSON array of up to five reviews.". The Google My Business API has support for fetching all reviews at [up to 50 per page](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/rest/v4/accounts.locations/batchGetReviews), but you must register as the owner of the business to get access.